# gluon SceneBuilder ToggleButtonGroup doesnt include getSelectedToggle() method

Tags: javafx, java-8, fxml, scenebuilder, gluon

I am trying to create a `ToggleButton` inside a `ToggleGroup` but the `ToggleButtonGroup` class that is provided in the scene builder does not include `getSelectedToggle()` method which will allow me to manipulate the selected toggle state. this method however, is included in the `ToggleGroup` class, but unfortunately the class does not exist in the scenebuilder..

Even if the `ToggleGroup` class is enabled it will be difficult, since it doesn't extend `javafx.scene.Node`...

Is there any way I can use the `getSelectedToggle()` method with the class `ToggleButtonGroup`? If not how is there a way I can get past this?

thanks in advance...

this is my code when i tried using `ToggleGroup`:

```xml
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="799.9999000000025" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.medicalManagement.LoginScreen.LoginScreenController">
  <children>
    <Pane prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="640.0" />
    <Pane layoutX="641.0" layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="640.0">
      <children>
        <Label layoutX="18.0" layoutY="168.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="Username">
          <font>
            <Font size="14.0" fx:id="x1" />
          </font>
        </Label>
        <TextField fx:id="userName" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="213.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" />
        <Label font="$x1" layoutX="264.0" layoutY="168.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="Password" />
        <Button fx:id="login" layoutX="19.0" layoutY="372.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="171.0" text="Log In" />
        <Separator layoutY="129.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="425.0" prefWidth="0.0" />
            <PasswordField id="passWord" fx:id="passWord" layoutX="238.0" layoutY="211.0" prefWidth="171.0" />
            <Label fx:id="dbStatus" layoutX="501.0" layoutY="756.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
          <ToggleGroup fx:id="userToggleGroup" toggles="adminToggle, nurseToggle">
              <RadioButton fx:id="adminToggle" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Admin" />
              <RadioButton fx:id="nurseToggle" layoutX="206.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Nurse" />
          </ToggleGroup>
      </children>
    </Pane>
  </children>
</Pane>
```

this is the `controller` class code:

```
package com.medicalManagement.LoginScreen;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ToggleButtonGroup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class LoginScreenController implements Initializable{

    LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
  @FXML
  private TextField userName;
  @FXML
  private PasswordField passWord;
  @FXML
  private Button login;
  @FXML
  private ToggleGroup userToggleGroup;
  @FXML
  private ToggleButton adminToggle;
  @FXML
  private ToggleButton nurseToggle;
  @FXML
  private Label dbStatus;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


            if (this.loginModel.isDbConnected()){
                this.dbStatus.setText("connected to database");
            }else {
                this.dbStatus.setText("database not connected");
            }

            this.adminToggle.setUserData("Admin");
            this.nurseToggle.setUserData("Nurse");
           this.adminToggle.setToggleGroup(userToggleGroup);
            this.nurseToggle.setToggleGroup(userToggleGroup);


    }

    public  void login(){
        try{
            if (this.loginModel.isLogin(this.userName.getText(), this.passWord.getText(),this.userToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString())){
                Stage stage = (Stage)this.login.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();
                switch (this.userToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString()){
                    case "Admin":
                        adminLogin();
                        break;
                    case "Nurse":
                        nurseLogin();
                        break;
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println(this.userName.getText());
                System.out.println(this.passWord.getText());
                System.out.println(this.userToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString());
            }
        }catch (Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(this.userName.getText());
            System.out.println(this.passWord.getText());
            System.out.println(this.userToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString());
        }
    }

    private void nurseLogin() {
    }

    public void adminLogin(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `Controller` code?

Comment: You `Controller` is questionable. You have `public static void main(String[] args) {}` in the `Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

`ToggleButtonGroup` does not seem to allow this. You'd need to iterate through the toggles and check for the selected one.

`ToggleGroup` is simply a property of `Toggle` that can to keep all the toggles of the group from selecting multiple toggles at once. It's not a layout but a value assigned to the `toggleGroup` property of the `Toggle`s.

You can use SceneBuilder to define `ToggleGroup`s:

1. Select the `RadioButton`
2. Under `Properties` type the `fx:id` for your `ToggleGroup` in the `Toggle Group` field.
3. For all other `RadioButton`s in the same `ToggleGroup` assign the same value to the `Toggle Group` property.

Or in the fxml:

```xml
...
<children>
    <Label layoutX="18.0" layoutY="168.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="Username">
      <font>
        <Font size="14.0" fx:id="x1" />
      </font>
    </Label>
    <TextField fx:id="userName" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="213.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" />
    <Label font="$x1" layoutX="264.0" layoutY="168.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="Password" />
    <Button fx:id="login" layoutX="19.0" layoutY="372.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="171.0" text="Log In" />
    <Separator layoutY="129.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="425.0" prefWidth="0.0" />
    <PasswordField id="passWord" fx:id="passWord" layoutX="238.0" layoutY="211.0" prefWidth="171.0" />
    <Label fx:id="dbStatus" layoutX="501.0" layoutY="756.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
    <RadioButton fx:id="adminToggle" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Admin">
        <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="userToggleGroup"/>
        </toggleGroup>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton fx:id="nurseToggle" layoutX="206.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Nurse">
        <toggleGroup>
            <fx:reference source="userToggleGroup"/>
        </toggleGroup>
    </RadioButton>
</children>
...
```

Comment: thank you.... but can i use the     ToggleButtonGroup also like this, the design is cool, but i cant get it to work...

Comment: @OlalekanAdebari It's not possible, since `ToggleButtonGroup` is a `Node` and cannot also extend `ToggleGroup`. Furthermore it wouldn't make much sense, since you can set `ToggleButtonGroup.selectionType` to `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE` but selecting multiple toggles would be prevented by a `ToggleGroup`. For `ToggleButtonGroup` your only option seems to be iterating through the toggles: `public static ToggleButton getSelectedButton(ToggleButtonGroup tbg) { for (ToggleButton tb : tbg.getToggles()) {if (tb.isSelected()) return tb;} return null; }`